# Shutdown Freezes on Ubuntu 14.04 (2015 Macbook Pro Dual-Boot)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, shutdown

I recently did a dual-boot on my 2015 Macbook Pro Retina. I opted not to use rEFInd, instead selecting sda1 (/boot/efi) as the mountpoint for my boot partition.

I cannot shut down my computer without it freezing on the splash screen. Thus, I have to force shutdown every time I want to switch to my Mac OS, which is terrible for the machine.

I've tried multiple things, including:

- Erasing my whole Ubuntu dual-boot and restarting from scratch
- Changing the line in /etc/default/grub from:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  ```

  to

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
  ```

  and to

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off quiet splash"
  ```

  and to

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
  ```

  and updating grub, none of which worked.
- I have a 16GB swap partition (which I later found out was too big) which I turned off and reformated to ext4 which didn't solve the problem.

I dont know what else to try. I suspect that the system doesn't know I'm booting from the EFI partition which might be affecting shutdown?

Currently, the output that's displaying during shutdown is:

```
All processes ended within 1 seconds...

[skipping]

Deactivating swap...
Unmounting local filesystems...
Will now halt
[704....] reboot: Power down
_
```

I'm pretty unfamiliar with this kind of debugging, so I've probably already done something wrong. I'd appreciate any help/explanation. Thanks.

Comment: If it's saying "Will now halt", then I think a hard shutdown is fine.